# How can I center align text content depending on a subset of that text?

Tags: html, css

I have an inline flex div were I would like to create an effect using the words wrap and the div overflow.

Basically, when the window is resized, some of the words of the sentence disappear and change the meaning of the sentence. You will then get, depending on the width:

- *We do fun rocket design* **science**
- *We do fun rocket* **science**
- *We do fun* **science**
- *We do* **science**

Here is a working snippet to illustrate what I mean:

```css
.text-container {
  font-size: 4.0rem;
  line-height: 1.2;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-inline-flex;
  display: inline-flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-align-content: space-around;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: distribute;
  align-content: space-around;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
.div1 {
  max-height: 100px;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 15px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.div2 {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-container">
  <h3 class="div1"> We do fun rocket design</h3> 
  <h3 class="div2"> science</h3>
</div>
```

You need to resize your window width and the words are going to disappear from the blue zone.

Here is my question:

Is there a way with css to center the line depending on the text displayed? I assume there is none but I wanted to check with the wizards out there.

Comment: Split the words with spans, not separate h3 and then use text align center on the h3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using flex, I would use spans and media queries:

```css
.heading {
  text-align: center;
}
@media (max-width: 20em) {
  .hide1 {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 15em) {
  .hide2 {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 10em) {
  .hide3 {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="text-container">
  <h3 class="heading"> 
    We do 
    <span class="hide3">fun </span>
    <span class="hide2">rocket </span>
    <span class="hide1">design </span>
    science 
  </h3>
</div>
```

[Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hffk1xL3/1/)

Comment: Good job. I can only use that for mobiles width with portrait orientation but it turns out it is the only case where I need to center the text :). Thank you.